# Android ViewPager loading data in background (asynctask vs thread+handler)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask, handler

I am currently using a viewpager and showing a layout with a progressbar(spinner) while data is loading.

My current architecture is using a asynctask with a callback to notify the fragment when my asynctask hits onPostExecute().

I used the callback method because if I use the .get() method, the asynctask stops being asynchronous  and the progress bar stops when the asynctask is at doInBackGround().
(If I use get to return the data from doInBackground it blocks my UI thread so I implement an interface in the fragment and send it to the asynctask and call the method from onPostExecute to notify the fragment that is has finished loading)

It's very irritating to have a callback for each asynctask because I have a lot of then and I something forget which comes first in order.

I use the asynctask to load some data from mySQL via php post and jSON.

My question is whether I should continue loading data with asynctask and use a callback to notify the fragment it has finished or use a worker thread and a handler to update the UI using received data.

```
public interface UpdateValuesAsyncResponse {
    void updateFinish();
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateValuesAsyncResponse{

     new UpdateLocalDevices(this).execute();

     @Override
     public void updateFinish() {

         continue();

     }

}

public class UpdateLocalDevices extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



   public UpdateLocalDevices(UpdateValuesAsyncResponse asyncResponse, Context context) {
       this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       getFromMySQL();
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       asyncResponse.updateFinish();
   }

}
```

Comment: i think you really need to rewrite your question, clear question help us understand your problem and help you get solution fast. explain more about the situation, really hard for me to know what is going on.

Comment: hope is clear now, short story I don't use .get() so I use a callback to know when the asynctask is finished

Comment: first of all you do not need any call back for asynctask because onPostexecute runs on UI thread so you can change or access whatever you like.

Comment: it's a heavy duty call, is the asynctask fit?

Comment: post how I can update the values got in asynctask to my fragment and I'll accept the answer, thank you !

Comment: what do you want to update? is it in a fragment layout or it is in activity of fragment? also it is widget or not?

Comment: It's fragment from a ViewPager, I need to update some ArrayLists of the fragment that calls the AsyncTask
The arraylists will update some seekbars.

I could pass the fragment to asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

first i assume that function `getFromMySQL();` returns object, you can replace it by string or anything else, and i assume you want to add those object to `myList` you can do what logic you want for example loop over the list and update or ...

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateValuesAsyncResponse{

     ArrayList<object> myList = new ArrayList<object>();

     new UpdateLocalDevices(this).execute();

     @Override
     public void updateFinish() {

         continue();

     }

}

public class UpdateLocalDevices extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {



   public UpdateLocalDevices(UpdateValuesAsyncResponse asyncResponse, Context context) {
       this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       return getFromMySQL();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
        myList.add(result[0]);
   }

}
```

Comment: pay attention to my code `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>` and ... Ur always welcome:-)

Comment: basic, DataType for getting , DataType for pusblishProgress, DataType for return

Comment: yes: AsyncTask<pass to doinbackground, pass to pusblishProgress, pass to onpostexecute>